# Xamarin.Form could not load Xamarin.iOS on the building of Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am blocked with a strange error while building the Android project in a Xamarin.Forms solution.

When I build the Android project I get the following error:

Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: could not load assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8404fff9cb79065'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio has added a reference to that assembly while adding a `using` statement. Can you verify in your `References` of your Android project that `Xamarin.iOS` wasn't added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after all, I did R&N on it neither found any solution for it then I had decided that I will remove @Android Project and again add it with all reference and import NuGet package.

:- when I have followed this step problem has been resolved.